# Stop javascript when the game is over

Tags: javascript, game-physics

How do I stop the game from running in the background. This simple pong game is for a school task. It shows showingGameOverScreen when ballX < 0. Then I want the game to break, or stop. Until I can for example write "click to restart the Game".

Same with the when player1Score == 1, "showingWinScreen".

```js
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

var ballX = 300;
var ballY = 200;
var ballSpeedX = 5;
var ballSpeedY = 5;

var player1Score = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 1;
var showingWinScreen = false;
var showingGameoverScreen = true;

var paddle1Y = 150;
const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
    drawEverything();
    moveEverything();
  }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true, );
  //sets the function for paddle handling
  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;

    switch (keyCode) {
      case 38:
        paddle1Y -= 5;
        break;
      case 40:
        paddle1Y += 5;
        break;
      default:
        // Avoid preventDefault() when not pressing expected keys
        return;
    }
    // Don't scroll window when pressing UP/DOWN
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function winningScore() {
  if (player1Score == WINNING_SCORE) {
    showingWinScreen = true;
  }
}

function ballReset() {
  //ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  ballX = canvas.width / 2;
  ballY = canvas.height / 2;
}

function moveEverything() {
  //ballX bouncing back
  ballX = ballX - ballSpeedX;
  //ball starting Y angle
  ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

  if (ballX < 0 /*600*/ ) {
    if (ballY > paddle1Y &&
      ballY < paddle1Y + PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    }
  }
  if (ballX > canvas.width /*600*/ ) {
    /*ballSpeedX=5;*/
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    player1Score += 1;
    winningScore();
    this.removeEventListener(event.type, moveEverything);
  }

  if (ballY < 0 /*600*/ ) {
    /*ballSpeedX=5;*/
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;

  }

  if (ballY > canvas.height /*400*/ ) {
    /*ballSpeedX=5;*/
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
}

//draws all on the gameCanvas wich is black.
function drawEverything() {
  //Next line blanks the screen with black
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");

  if (ballX < 0) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
    canvasContext.fillText("GameOver", canvas.width / 2, 200);
    return;
  }

  if (showingWinScreen) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
    if (player1Score == WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("You Won!", canvas.width / 2, 200);
    }
    return;
  }

  //next line draw left paddle
  colorRect(0, paddle1Y, PADDLE_THICKNESS, PADDLE_HEIGHT, "white");
  //next line draws ball from the function
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, "white");
  canvasContext.fillText(player1Score, 100, 100);
}

// summerize the ball information
function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

//summerize the canvas info, like; Color and width/height
function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's certainly related to the question you linked @Liam, but in this case, I believe that Jamn Nemn didn't know enough about `setInterval` to be able to ask that question. Thus I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your game loop by calling `setInterval` you need to retrieve the ID of the interval it returns.

Now when you know the game is over, you need to stop that game loop by calling `clearInterval` with the ID of your game loop previously retrieved.

```
var gameLoopInterval = setInterval(function() {
    drawEverything();
    moveEverything();
  }, 1000/framesPerSecond);

// Later on, when the game is over
clearInterval(gameLoopInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `setInterval` that drives your game loop and clear it when you no longer need it running.

```
// Start the game.
var gameInterval = setInterval();
// Stop the game.
clearInterval(gameInterval);
```